Connection to render.com Postgres server locally
I need your help with this issue.
I wrote a python script to connect to postgres but commands are not executed.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from os import getenv
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import text

# Define a function to execute SQL script
def execute_sql_script(engine, script_file):
    """Execute SQL script"""
    with open(script_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        sql_script = file.read()
        print("File read")

    with engine.connect() as connection:
        try:
            print("trying to execute sql script")
            connection.execute(text(sql_script))
            print("SQL script executed successfully.")
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            print("Error executing SQL script:", e)

def main():
    db_url = f"postgresql://user:xxxxx@dpg-cov771o21fec73ffrp8g-a.frankfurt-postgres.render.com/cheese_db"

    try:
        # Create SQLAlchemy engine
        engine = create_engine(db_url)

        # Create a session
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()

        # Path to your SQL script files
        script_files = ['website/static/sql/set_up.sql', 'website/static/sql/add_data.sql']

        # Execute SQL script
        for script_file in script_files:
            execute_sql_script(engine, script_file)

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print("Error:", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

So the first script is supposed to create tables, and the second one adds data. But the second one returns an error that tables do not exist (so the first script was never executed!)
This is the output:
File read
trying to execute sql script
SQL script executed successfully.
File read
trying to execute sql script
Error executing SQL script: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "source" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO source (name) VALUES


I think you should end the try block with an else: connection.commit() because when the connection closes without commit then the changes are not saved for the next time you connect, and the table that you've created in the first script is not saved for the next script.

The solution was to add connection.commit()  after connection.execute()

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
